# Auto-fill Relate field in SuiteCRM

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

How can we Auto-fill a Relate Field in SuiteCRM. I have a Property associated with a Lead and i want to auto-fill the property(relate field) in Convert lead form if there is any property associated with the that Lead.
I am using SuiteCRM 7.7.9

Answer (score 0):

You can fill relate field in preDisplay() function of module.
On conditional basis in pre display like:
$this->bean->relate_field_id = 'record_id'